If I shake a container of water, what type of wave will propagate?
I am very used to dealing with body waves, but I am a bit confused by water waves. As a side effect of an imaging experiment, we are introducing kiloherz mechanical waves into a small volume of water (around 1 cm by 1 cm by 1 mm) and want to understand the generated waves better. Since restoring forces are only surface tension and gravity (If I understood everything right), does the depth of the container influnce the wave speed? Are there guided waves present like in a thing sheet of an elastic material? I would be super happy if you could give me some intuition or good sources on this, all I could find are pages and pages on ocean waves. Thanks and all the best!
EDIT: Sorry for being unclear: Shaking means using a piezoelectric actuator to move the tub in plane with the water surface at anywhere between 2000 and 10000 Hz with about 10 µm total displacement. No rotation, just translation

Depends how you shake it, no?

Does “shaking” involve rotation or translation, and on what axes, and how much, and at what frequency, and with what time variance?

Thank you, added a clarification!

the velocity of the surface wave depends on the depth of the container, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/824005/would-the-angle-of-diffraction-past-a-slit-be-different-for-water-versus-a-diffe/824040#824040
